# Issues when trying to find a file on EFS from an EC2 instance running Perl 5

Tags: rhel, perl, amazon-ec2

We have Perl 5 installed on EC2 instance running RHEL 8.  When we try and run perl script to located a file on EFS, it takes around a minute to locate the file after it was created on the EFS.  There is no such delay if we search the EFS from an EC2 instance without Perl installed

Similary even if we look for the file on EFS from the Ec2 where Perl is installed without running Perl script, there is still a 30 to 60 sec delay until the file can be located

All the Perl 5 libraries seem to be there and up to date

Any ideas on what could be causing the delay in locating the file from the Ec2 that has Perl 5 installed?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.